# Extracting a specified value from a mySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write this function of this program that will extract a value (one that they click on from a list of values) from a mySQL table.  When I write this code, It always gives me the error "No database Selected."

I am trying to extract values from a table (performed_in) inside of the schema movies.  The user selects a name, then the program is supposed to search the table "performed_in" and return values (all of the fields) that match what the user selected.

Even if my type something like this, it doesnt connect.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'uMoviesUser', '');
```

The problem seems to be inside of the  query line.  What is wrong with it?

```
 $moviesdb = new mysqli('localhost', 'uMoviesUser', '', 'movies');
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo '<h3>Database Access Error!</h3>';
 }
 else {
 $select = "select * from performed_in";
 $select .= " where name = '".$_GET['name']."'";
 $res = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
 echo $row;
 }
```

Comment: You are mixing mysqli and mysql functions! These are two entirely separate database interfaces. Stick to one or the other. If you still have problems with code that *should* work, please try again and tell us the exact problem and error messages.

Comment: This actually fixed it.  I was using new mysqli('etc', 'etc', 'etc'), but when I brought it to mysqli('etc','etc','etc') it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above comment u havn't used a the function to select the database which is mysql_select_db

```
  $db_selected = mysql_select_db('urDB', $connection);
    if (!$db_selected) {
       die ('Can\'t use urDB: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using new mysqli('etc', 'etc', 'etc'), but when I brought it to mysqli('etc','etc','etc') it worked.

The others solutions weren't really any closer then my original one.